# Enviar variable php de un blade a un controlador laravel

Tags: php, laravel-blade

Importe un documento de excel el cual necesitaba hacer uno calculos a una columna en especifio y mostrarlos antes de realizar el paso siguiente el cual es cambiar la posicion de las columnas a como el usuario crea conveniente antes de insertarlos en una BD(Eso lo tengo bien claro como hacerlo) pero como para mostrarlos los cargue en un blade con codigo php ahora no tengo claro como retornar esa tabla con los calculos ya realizados a mi controlador como variable global para usarla en una funcion donde insertare los campos en la BD, alguien podria orientarme o sabe como hacerlo.

**blade.php**

```
<body>
    <table> 
        <tbody>
            @php
            {{

                $primeraFila=reset($excel);
                $primera=count($primeraFila);
                
                for($i = 1; $i < $primera+1; $i++){
                    
                    echo "<label>";
                        echo"Columna $i ";
                    echo "</label>";

                }
          
              

                foreach ($excel as $a) {   

                    echo "<tr >";

                                for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++){

                                    $patron= "/^[0-9]+'-.*$/";

                                    if(preg_match($patron,$a[$i])==true){
                                        
                                        $indice=$i;
                                        $largo=$a[$indice];
                                        
                                        $pies=explode("'-","$largo'-");
                                        $pulgadas=explode(" ","$pies[1] ");
                                        
                                        
                                        $pulgadasEnteras=$pulgadas[0];
                                        $pulgadasfracciones=$pulgadas[1];
                                        $piesEnteros=$pies[0];


                                        $nnum=explode("/", "$pulgadasfracciones/");

                                        if($nnum[1]>0){
                                            $result = intval($nnum[0]) / intval($nnum[1]);
                                        }else{
                                            $result=0;
                                        } 
                                        
                                        $a[$indice]=$result;
                                    }

                                        echo "<td>".$a[$i]."</td>";
                                      

                                }

                            
                    echo "</tr>";

                }
                
         

               
            }}
            @endphp
        </tbody>    
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Les comento como lo resolvi por si a alguien le llega a servir... guarde cada celda en un nuevo arreglo y lo mande en un form usando un input oculto con json_encode & lo recibo en mi controlador con json_decode.